# How do display image from an Image column in a custom row formatter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a list with an Image column and 3 descriptor fields. I want to create a custom display that has the image in section 1 and the 3 descriptors stacked in section 2. I can't figure out how to get the image to display.

```
   "elmType": "img",
   "style": {"width": "150px","height": "125px"},
   "attributes": {"src": "[$myImage]"}
```

The idea is to display the image associated with the list item.

I've seen many examples where the src value is coded to a specific image. That's not the purpose here. Think product catalog.

So - how do I get the image to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `[$myImage.serverRelativeUrl]` instead of `[$myImage]` to get the image URL & show it using JSON Formatting.

**Documentation**: [Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values) - Check "Image fields" section.

**Related Read**: [SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh!!!!  This worked.  Simultaneously - one of my developers also walked me to the same solution!!!!